# How can I write a tower of unions?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

Here is the figure I want to write on latex:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what is the correct name of this figure and how to form it in latex please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can place the entries in a `matrix` using the `amsmath` package:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\cup & & \cup & & \cup\\
L_3(I_1) & \subset & L_3(I_2) & \subset & L_3(I_3) & \subset & \cdots\\
\cup & & \cup & & \cup\\
L_2(I_1) & \subset & L_2(I_2) & \subset & L_2(I_3) & \subset & \cdots\\
\cup & & \cup & & \cup\\
L_1(I_1) & \subset & L_1(I_2) & \subset & L_1(I_3) & \subset & \cdots
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you want to reduce the spacing between columns, you can add `\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}` (or whatever spacing seems right to you) before `\begin{matrix}`.
[image]

It's best to enclose the adjustment in `\begingroup..\endgroup` to ensure you don't affect spacing in the rest of your document:

```
\[
\begingroup
\setlength\arraycolsep{1.5pt}
\begin{matrix}
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots\\
\cup & & \cup & & \cup\\
L_3(I_1) & \subset & L_3(I_2) & \subset & L_3(I_3) & \subset & \cdots\\
\cup & & \cup & & \cup\\
L_2(I_1) & \subset & L_2(I_2) & \subset & L_2(I_3) & \subset & \cdots\\
\cup & & \cup & & \cup\\
L_1(I_1) & \subset & L_1(I_2) & \subset & L_1(I_3) & \subset & \cdots
\end{matrix}
\endgroup
\]
```

Comment: Probably you should reduce the value of `\arraycolsep`.

Comment: I thought the unreduced version looked most like the OP's example, but you're right. I'll add the option to my response.

Comment: I had prepared almost the same answer as you, with \àrraycolsep set to 2pt. Try it, to see if you think it's correct.

Comment: I thought 1.5pt looked more like the natural spacing one would find in `L_1(I_1)\subset L_1(I_2)`

Comment: Quite possible. I didn't think of testing.

Answer (score 8):

You can see that `\cup` is not a rotated `\subset` symbol.

In order to get the standard spacing around relation symbols, it's better to set `\arraycolsep` to zero and rely on TeX's own method, by adding `{}` fore and aft.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,graphicx}

\newcommand{\rotsubset}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\subset$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ *{7}{ >{{}}c<{{}} } }
\vdots     &         & \vdots     &         & \vdots \\
\rotsubset &         & \rotsubset &         & \rotsubset \\
L_3(I_1)   & \subset & L_3(I_2)   & \subset & L_3(I_3) & \subset & \cdots \\
\rotsubset &         & \rotsubset &         & \rotsubset \\
L_2(I_1)   & \subset & L_2(I_2)   & \subset & L_2(I_3) & \subset & \cdots \\
\rotsubset &         & \rotsubset &         & \rotsubset \\
L_1(I_1)   & \subset & L_1(I_2)   & \subset & L_1(I_3) & \subset & \cdots
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Your image is a commutative diagram of inclusions, so you may want to use the package `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    \vdots
    &
    \vdots
    &
    \vdots
    &
    {}
    \\
    L_3(I_1)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    L_3(I_2)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    L_3(I_3)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    \cdots
    \\
    L_2(I_1)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    L_2(I_2)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    L_2(I_3)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    \cdots
    \\
    L_1(I_1)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    L_1(I_2)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    L_1(I_3)
    \arrow[phantom]{u}[rotate=90]{\subset}
    \arrow[phantom]{r}{\subset}
    &
    \cdots
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]